# Response size limit when using Apache HttpComponents

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

I am converting some code from the Http Client 3.x library over to the Http Components 4.x library. The old code contains a check to make sure that the response is not over a certain size. This is fairly easy to do in Http Client 3.x since you can get back a stream from the response using the getResponseBodyAsStream() method and determine when the size has been exceeded. I can't find a similar way in Http Components.

Here's the old code as an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
private static final long RESPONSE_SIZE_LIMIT = 1024 * 1024 * 10;
private static final int READ_BUFFER_SIZE = 16384;

private static ByteArrayOutputStream readResponseBody(HttpMethodBase method)
        throws IOException {

    int len;
    byte buff[] = new byte[READ_BUFFER_SIZE];
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    long byteCount = 0;

    in = method.getResponseBodyAsStream();

    out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(READ_BUFFER_SIZE);

    while ((len = in.read(buff)) != -1 && byteCount <= RESPONSE_SIZE_LIMIT) {
        byteCount += len;
        out.write(buff, 0, len);
    }

    if (byteCount >= RESPONSE_SIZE_LIMIT) {
        throw new IOException(
                "Size limited exceeded reading from HTTP input stream");
    }

    return (out);

}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the HttpEntity.getContent()?

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then to make it easier for others to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *HttpEntity.getContent()* to get an *InputStream* to read from yourself.