# Apache HTTP Compoonents size limit response?

Tags: java, memory, jvm, dos, apache-httpcomponents

I connect to server that juts returns non-finite stream of "A". I.e: this

```
$ nc 1.2.3.4 9001
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA^C
```

seems apache http component library just gets entire response from server and then parses. how to limit the size so JVM wont crash?

This is my code:

w/ fluent API:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    Request.Get(url).execute().discardContent();
}
```

w/ low level API:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    String url = "http://1.2.3.4:9001/";
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    System.out.println("A");
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    System.out.println("B");
    HttpResponse hr = httpclient.execute(request);
    System.out.println("C");
}
```

gets me this:

```
A
B
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer.expand(ByteArrayBuffer.java:62)
    at org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer.append(ByteArrayBuffer.java:92)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:278)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:92)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:62)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:712)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:517)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
    at com.dudebro.WhatHappen.main(WhatHappen.java:103)
```

Note [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482160/response-size-limit-when-using-apache-httpcomponents) is irrelevant, i don't even ask API for response body and it still crashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try setting the following parameters:

```
MAX_LINE_LENGTH = "http.connection.max-line-length"
MAX_HEADER_COUNT = "http.connection.max-header-count"
```

I think the default for the first one is -1 which means no limit.

Comment: _thank you_ bro. "http.connection.max-line-length" fix it. i guess thing probably accept non-finite headers as well better check on that.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is clear from the stack trace: `BufferedReader.readLine()` keeps growing its buffer since it can't find a line terminator to start parsing the response status line, until the JVM runs out of memory. You can wrap your code in a `try` block and catch `OutOfMemoryError`, or even submit a patch to Apache maintainers, but I don't think you should really take this issue into account for a real-world application.

That server is not HTTP-compliant because the infinite stream of "A"s isn't definitely a valid HTTP reponse status-line. Usually servers are designed to be liberal for what they accept and strict for what they send, ie they should take into account that there may be uncompliant clients into the wild.

On the other side, often client developers assume that the server is well-implemented because, if it isn't, then the business running the server won't get any client...

In this case it's clear that the target server doesn't provide any valuable service, since it isn't even protocol-compliant, so nobody can take anything from it, Google can't index it, so who would spread the public URL to such an application? I think it's fine that the client crashes on your development machine because it tells that the server program is not working. If it's under your control you can fix it, otherwise you'll switch service provider. Again, this is not going to happen in the real world, because such a bad service will crash all of its clients and nobody will use it.

In the comments you said it's a server application that accept user-submitted URLs. In that case, you should really set a limit for the line length to avoid that a malicious user brings your server down.

Comment: `BufferedReader.readLine() keeps growing its buffer ` that what i thought figured there would be a way around it without modifying the library. and no disagree 100% with rest of post. dont want entire vm and everything crash just cus one (out of 100) server is bad. buying a separate machine or vm for each connection is dumb, no reason server should send bogus crap in first place. "liberal for what they accept" doesnt mean crashing, nor does it mean be braindead

Comment: *Servers should be liberal in what they accept* says **server**, while you are developing a **client**, and it means that server developers must watch out for misbehaving clients. Of course a client should not crash either, and you can prevent this, but I was pointing out that for obvious reasons this is not a common concern. I don't know what your application does, so I can't tell further

Comment: client uses 100 servers. if 1/100 servers is evil that dont mean client should stop functrioning. client doesnt depend on 1/100 server thus should not break from this

Comment: Againg, I'm not stating that your client should crash. I'm stating that since I don't know your environment and your requirements, I can't tell if it's really a valuable concern. Please, try to understand my answer: you need a public URL to access a server, and if that server doesn't provide any service, why would anyone ask for that URL? The only interested users would be malicious ones, so I stated that depending on your application, those users may be a concern or not

Comment: exactly, you are thinking of only one use case not about mine. client can submit his server URL for me to callback. ither way on your use case its still wrong to crash on bad server because app could use multiple servers and provide critical service. one server could choose to crash me app at a critical time: i.e: when im about to save result of heavy computation to persistance or about to activate sheild to block iCBM asttack, etc, etc, etc. so sayin server has no motive is the dumb

Comment: In that case there's a valid reason to check for lines length